# How to extract the column names from a sql query

Tags: python, mysql, regex

I have extracted just the column fields from a query like this

```
query_split = [query[query.find("select") + len("select"): query.find("from")]]
```

I get a string like this

```
 query_split = [' service,count(*) as count,round(sum(mrp),2) as sale ']
```

I want to get a list which looks like this

```
[' service','count(*) as count','round(sum(mrp),2) as sale']
```

This is because I want to get the list of column names

```
['service','count','sale']
```

I have tried other methods such as

```
for file in reader(query_split):
    print(file)
```

Gives me the output

```
[' service', 'count(*) as count', 'round(sum(mrp)', '2) as sale ']
```

when i took the test case which uses round(sum(mrp),2) type operation in query the below function failed at that point

```
def get_column_name(query):
    """
    Extracts the column name from a sql query
    :param query: str
    :return: column_name
    list: Column names which that query will fetch
    """
    column_name=[]
    query_split = query[query.find("select") + len("select"): query.find("from")]
    for i in query_split.split(','):

        if "as" in i:
            column_name.append(i.split('as')[-1])
        else:
            column_name.append(i.split(' ')[-1])
    return column_name
```

Comment: Do you, by chance, execute the queries you want to dissect? If so, and if you use a DBAPI 2 compliant library, the [description attribute](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description) of the cursor might help you out.

Comment: No @shmee ,this query will be used for an api .

Comment: As I understand, you are trying to get the columns' name by text processing? Assuming you have no prior information about the query?

Comment: How far do you want to take this? Is this a one-off job or something regular that needs to be automated?

Comment: @wp78de It will be used for automated.I have solved the issue to one point but failed at this test case.Updated my question with how got the column names for simple query but failed when query had some in query operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the SQL at play here features nested constructs.

The most likely cleanest solution is to have a SQL parser that understands the MySQL dialect. Arguably, it can be done most easily with ANTLR; you can find a [MySQL grammar here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/mysql) and a [quick guide here](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-any-language-in-java-in-5-minutes-using-antlr-for-example-python/) if you are curious.

To approach this with regex we need to account for balanced parenthesis with a recursive regex in a match pattern like this:

```
[^,]+(\((?>[^()]++|(?1))*+\))[^,]+|([^(),]+(?:,|$))
```

**Explanation**:

- `[^,]+(\((?>[^()]++|(?1))*+\))[^,]+` the recursive regex to match pairs of `()` and everything inbetween (including commas) sourounded by a negated character class that matches everything but a comma.
- `([^(),]+(?:,|$))` matches regular columns

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/X17qNF/2/)

Sample Code:

```
import regex as re
regex = r"[^,]+(\((?>[^()]++|(?1))*+\))[^,]+|([^(),]+(?:,|$))"
test_str = "service,count(*) as count,round(sum(mrp),2) as sale,count(*) as count2,round(sum(mrp),2) as sale2"
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
result = [match.group() for match in matches]
```

Outputs:

```
['service,', 'count(*) as count', 'round(sum(mrp),2) as sale', 'count(*) as count2', 'round(sum(mrp),2) as sale2']
```

Since we are using PCRE regex features you will need to install Python's alternative [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) package to run the code. Good luck.

Comment: woah! Thanks for a wonderful solution.Can you suggest where can I understand this regex expression from, so that I can use them myself later.